# sqlnet bytes sent in timings on

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I ran an execution plan with AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY and TIMING ON but had a question about a few of things in there:

```
121548468  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
278853  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
25309  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
```

I see the above and just wnat to confirm what I read online. Does the first line mean that I Oracle sent 115.9Mb to my laptop (I ran this via Sql*Plus on my laptop) and my laptop sent back .26Mb and it took a total of 25309 round trips over the network to get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much, yes.

I think SQL*Plus extract this data from [V$SESSTAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/stats002.htm#i375475), in which these stats are described as:

> - **bytes received via SQL*Net from client**: Total number of bytes received from the client over Oracle Net Services
> - **bytes sent via SQL*Net to client**: Total number of bytes sent to the client from the foreground processes
> - **SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client**: Total number of Oracle Net Services messages sent to and received from the client